# Induction powers of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to prove that if $A = AB-BA$, where $A,B$ are squared matrices, then
$$kA^k = A^kB-BA^k$$ for all $k$ in naturals.

I proceed by induction, but I can't arrange the expressions to conclude. Any hint?

Comment: I think you mean "square matrix," not "squared matrix."

Answer (score 2):

Assume the result for $k$; then

\begin{align*}
(k + 1)A^{k + 1} &= A\left(kA^k + A^k\right) \\
&= A \left(A^k B - B A^k + A^k\right) \\
&= A^{k + 1}B - ABA^k + A^{k + 1}
\end{align*}

Now use the fact that

$$AB = A + BA$$

to deal with the final two terms.